# Python: normalizing a text file

Tags: python, normalization, synonym

I have a text file which contains several spelling variants of many words:

For e.g.

```
identification ... ID .. identity...contract.... contr.... contractor...medicine...pills..tables
```

So I want to have a synonym text file which contains the words synonyms and would like to replace all the variants with the primary word. Essentially I want the normalize the input file.

For e.g my synonym list file would look like

```
identification = ID identify
contracting = contract contractor contractors contra...... 
word3 = word3_1 word3_2 word3_3 ..... word3_n
.
.
.
.
medicine = pills tables drugs...
```

I want the end output file to look like

```
identification ... identification .. identification...contractor.... contractor.... contractor...medicine...medicine..medicine
```

How do I got about programming in python?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the synonym file and convert it into a dictionary, `table`:

```
import re

table={}
with open('synonyms','r') as syn:
    for line in syn:
        match=re.match(r'(\w+)\s+=\s+(.+)',line)
        if match:
            primary,synonyms=match.groups()
            synonyms=[synonym.lower() for synonym in synonyms.split()]
            for synonym in synonyms:
                table[synonym]=primary.lower()

print(table)
```

yields

```
{'word3_1': 'word3', 'word3_3': 'word3', 'word3_2': 'word3', 'contr': 'contracting', 'contract': 'contracting', 'contractor': 'contracting', 'contra': 'contracting', 'identify': 'identification', 'contractors': 'contracting', 'word3_n': 'word3', 'ID': 'identification'}
```

Next, you could read in the text file, and replace each word with its primary synonym from `table`:

```
with open('textfile','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(''.join(table.get(word.lower(),word) 
                      for word in re.findall(r'(\W+|\w+)',line)))
```

yields

```
identification     identification    identity   contracting     contracting     contracting   medicine   medicine  medicine
```

---

1. `re.findall(r'(\w+|\W+)',line)` was used split each `line` while
   preserving whitespace. If whitespace is not of interest, you could
   also use the easier `line.split()`.
2. `table.get(word,word)` returns `table[word]` if word is in `table`,
   and simply returns `word` if `word` is not in the synonym `table`.

Comment: Whitespace splitting will append trailing punctuation - for example "Show me your ID." if split on whitespace, won't give the nice clean "ID" string to convert to "identification".  Upper/lower case will need to be handled too.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Thanks for the comment. I changed `\s+|\S+` to `\w+|\W+` to separate punctuation from words, and added code to handle case. @Pradeep: These changes have unlikely but possibly problematic consequences: words with punctuation (like `can't`) in the synonym list will no longer match, and words whose meaning changes with case (`Polish` is a nationality, but `polish` is a verb) may get replaced by the same synonym. These issues can be handled with more code, but let's not do that unless it affects your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought: Instead of having a list of *all* variation of a word, have a look at [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)

```
>>> get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])
['apple', 'ape']
>>> import keyword
>>> get_close_matches('wheel', keyword.kwlist)
['while']
>>> get_close_matches('apple', keyword.kwlist)
[]
>>> get_close_matches('accept', keyword.kwlist)
['except']
```

Comment: Thanks you..I will need this type of heuristics in scrubbing. I intend to look into this at a slightly more advanced stage of the application I am working on.